# NSTableView & CoreData: Delete Object at clicked row

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-data, nstableview

I am pretty new to Core Data and am currently working on a small (OSX) app that uses an `NSTableView` to organise objects. I would now like to delete a row/object with the click of a button on that targeted row.

I access the managed object within the table controller by calling `[NSApp managedObjectContext]` (still trying to figure out that dependency injection thing) but I can't easily delete an `objectAtIndex:` like I used to with the array (which has now been replaced by the core data stack, right?).

How do I identify the object to be deleted? And consequently, how can I cleanly remove it from the stack?

This is probably a really basic question but I couldn't find any resources on it. Bindings obviously don't work because the row does not get selected before the click occurs.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Thanks for formatting, Larme!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bindings would work, in that you could have the button's IBAction query the `objectValue` for the parent NSTableCellView.  Once you have that objectValue, you could call the bound arrayController to delete the object, and then the cell/row would disappear.

So, if you have a tableCellView that has a delete button with an IBAction, within that IBAction, you could get the sender's superview, ensure it's an NSTableCellView, get the objectValue, and call `[myArrayController removeObject:...]`

As it says in the NSTableCellView class reference:

> The objectValue is automatically set by the table when using bindings or is the object returned by the NSTableViewDataSource protocol method tableView:objectValueForTableColumn:row:.

This is actually a typical pattern with views in cocoa.  `objectValue` or often `representedObject` are properties on the views that refer to the data model objects they represent, so if you have a view pointer from `sender` on the IBAction, you can get the related data model object.   And if you're using bindings and a controller, you can then just have the controller remove that object.

With bindings, you will *often* create buttons that need IBActions attached, rather than some direct binding.  But those IBActions can most definitely interact with the controller and not the view.

And with core data, array controllers are *really* slick vs. assuming you have to do it all programmatically.

Comment: Thanks stevesliva, I did not get an Email notifying me of your response so I only saw this now.
I solved it by calling
`[[[NSApp delegate] managedObjectContext] deleteObject: mo2delete];` and getting the object with `[TableView selectRowIndexes: ...]`

Comment: No problem-- I still haven't gotten SO notifications set up the way I'd like.   Regarding the way you did it-- always several ways to do things, but I hadn't assumed that the row with the button was selected.  Your solution might not work if the table didn't allow selection.

Comment: I select the row via the sender as such:

`- (IBAction)buttonDelete:(id)sender {
    NSUInteger row = [TableView rowForView:sender];
    [TableView selectRowIndexes:[[NSIndexSet alloc] initWithIndex:row] byExtendingSelection:NO];
    
    [self deleteSelectedObjects];
}`
Seems a bit complicated but also allows me to do a multi-select at a later stage. Is this a bad style of programming it?

Comment: I don't see any issue with the way you did it.  It's view-centric vs. controller-centric in terms of how it accesses the linked model/view, but that's just different and either way the code's in your controller implementation.  I only commented to contrast my comments vs. yours-- it's possible without row selection.

Comment: This sounds very plausible but I fail to get this working. I'm working with Swift, but I guess things should still work similar. In my IBAction I get to the `NSTableCellView` through `sender.superview!` as described. But then this object does have an empty `objectValue` property... `let obj = (sender.superview! as NSTableCellView).objectValue!`. The Table View is bound to the ArrayController and the text fields in my Table Cell View show the content correctly. I just can't get to the objectValue/representedObject for a specific row in my delete method. Any ideas?

Comment: In fact, it actually works. For some weird reason a `println(obj)` delivers no output, but I can actually access the property of my core data object. So thanks for your response, it really helped!